# Upload file to form on intranet and email

Tags: html, asp.net, file-upload, webforms

We have a form on our company intranet where users put in data and then they click the submit data and that data gets compiled into an email and sent to a specific list of users.  We have the site.aspx.cs that I specify what data is being sent out through email.

We are adding a field where the user can upload a file when doing the form but I am having issues adding this to the .cs file so that it can send the data through the email.

This is the HTML where I created the field and the Upload button

```
<body>
<div class="containerContent">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="outer4ColLeft">
      <ul class="subnav">
        <li>
          <a href="../corporate_resources.aspx">Documents</a>
        </li>
          <li>
           <a href="../mission_ethics.aspx">Mission &amp; Ethics Statements</a>
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="../history.aspx">History</a>
          </li> 
          <li>
           <a href="../associate_profiles.aspx">Associate Profiles</a>
          </li>           
        <li class="activeSub">
          <a href="../corporate_form.aspx">Corporate Forms</a>
        </li>                 
      </ul>
<!--#include file="../includes/quicklinksForm.aspx"-->       
        </div>
        <div class="outer12ColRight">
            <h1>
                <span></span>
                <img height="45" alt="Odd Occurrence Report" src="../images/corporate/h1_oddOccurrence.jpg" />
            </h1>
            <div class="formContent">

<form id="form1" class="forms" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="formPanel" Visible="true" runat="server">
        <h3>Note: An odd occurrence is any unplanned interruption</h3>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="oddValidationSummary"  class=".redText" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>General</legend>
                        <div class="profileRow1Col1">
                            <p>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valPartNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPartNumber" ErrorMessage="Part Number is required.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                Part Number</p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valEmployeeID" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmployeeID" ErrorMessage="Employee ID is required.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                Employee ID</p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valCurrentJobNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCurrentJobNumber" ErrorMessage="Current Job Number is required.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                Current Job Number</p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valRevisionLevel" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRevisionLevel" ErrorMessage="Revision Level is required.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                Revision Level</p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valOperationNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtOperationNumber" ErrorMessage="Operation Number is required.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                Revision Level</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profileRow1Col2">
                            <p>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrentJobNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <p>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRevisionLevel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOperationNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Changes</legend>
                        <p>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valProposedChange" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtProposedChange" ErrorMessage="Proposed Change description is required." Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            Proposed Change</p>
                        <p>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProposedChange" runat="server" height="100px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="600px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </p>
                         <p>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valChangeReason" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtChangeReason" ErrorMessage="Reason for Proposed Change description is required." Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            Reason for Proposed Change</p>
                        <p>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtChangeReason" runat="server" height="100px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="600px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </p>


                     </fieldset>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnReset_Click" Text="Reset" />
                    </p>
```

Here is the .cs I currently have saying that the email is going to send these current fields in the body.  I need to know how to make the file uploaded in the HTML send as an attachment in this email.  Any ideas?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String toAddress = ""; String fromAddress = "doNotReply@companyemail.com";


        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.companyemail.com");

        smtpClient.Port = 25;

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.IsBodyHtml = false;
        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        try
        {

            message.Subject = "Program Change";
            message.Body = "Part Number: " + txtPartNumber.Text.Trim() + "\n";
            message.Body += "Employee ID: " + txtEmployeeID.Text.Trim() + "\n";
            message.Body += "Current Job Number: " + txtCurrentJobNumber.Text.Trim() + "\n" + "\n";
            message.Body += "Revision Level: " + txtRevisionLevel.Text.Trim() + "\n";
            message.Body += "Operation Number: " + txtOperationNumber.Text.Trim() + "\n";
            message.Body += "Proposed Changes: " + txtProposedChange.Text.Trim() + "\n";
            message.Body += "Reason for Proposed Change: " + txtChangeReason.Text.Trim() + "\n";
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["file"];
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(file.InputStream, file.FileName);
            message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            toAddress += "user@companyemail.com";


            smtpClient.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, message.Subject, message.Body);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            formPanel.Visible = false;
            errorPanel.Visible = true;


        }
        formPanel.Visible = false;
        errorPanel.Visible = false;
        successPanel.Visible = true;

}
```

Comment: I tagged it because I wasnt sure if the answer would remain in Dreamweaver or would be in PHP

Comment: I am novice at web design.  I use Dreamweaver for everything when changing the site.  I dabbled in PHP in the past so I wasnt sure.

Comment: ASP.NET is not PHP. They're not related, other than they both happen to be server side web development frameworks. Therefore, you shouldn't tag your question as PHP unless PHP is specifically involved. Similarly, don't tag your question as Dreamweaver unless your question specifically relates to some aspect of that IDE. Tagging helps us categorize the question and connect you with the right people to answer your question, so tagging the wrong things makes it more difficult for experts to find questions they can answer.

Comment: I'm just looking for some help here.  You already changed it so the tagging is a done deal

Comment: I know you're looking for help. I'm trying to help you learn to use this site better and make it more likely for someone knowledgeable about your issue to be able to find your question. Simply asking your question without tagging it properly makes it less likely to get seen by the people that can help. You don't have to worry about it. It's not like you're in trouble. Just trying to get you started off right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the file from the posted form.

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["file"];
```

Then, add it as an attachment.

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(file.InputStream, file.FileName);
message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Note, I haven't tested this code.

Comment: Where do I put the code you mentioned above?  I have changed my .cs above to reflect the entire thing

Comment: The first line clearly needs to be before the 2nd line, because the second line refers to the first. The third line needs to be after you declared the `message` object, since it depends on that. And clearly you need to attach the email before you send it.

Comment: Well I performed a test but I run into the design on the asp itself.  When I go to grab the file to upload the button to do the upload zeroes it out.  I click browse, find the file, it shows up next to browse, click upload, then disappears.  I left it in the browse area and hit submit but the attachment did not come through the email.

Comment: @Individual101 Check the network tab of your browser's debugging tools to see if your file gets uploaded to the server.

Comment: On the post submit screen?

Comment: @Individual101 On whatever webpage you have performing the upload, that's the page you need to make sure it's sending the data to the server properly.

Comment: When I click upload I dont see anything change in the debugging network tab

Comment: @Individual101 You don't see *anything* change? You should see something happen once you submit the form.

Comment: Before and after I only get:  200 | POST | ProgramChange.aspx | my.mydomain.com | html | 4.10 KB | 14.46 KB

Comment: DO you have any more advice on this issue?

Comment: @Individual101 That POST request to the server is your data being uploaded. Look in that POST request to see if the file is included in the upload.

Comment: No I do not see it.  It seems to me like when I browse to the file I am looking for it only elects the file.  I don't know if it is needed or not but should I have the upload button to upload the file to location out on the intranet folder and then show up on in a label or something on the page then when the submit button is pressed to grab that file and attach it to the email.

Comment: @Individual101 That's not really how it works. You have to submit the file to the web server, then the web server can do whatever it wants with it. Since you're using Web Forms, take a look at the [FileUpload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.110).aspx) control.

Comment: Well here is another issue I am having.  This page already has a <form> on it for everything else.  When I try to add the <form method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"> string it messes up

Comment: You can't have a form within a form, and you can only have one form with the `runat="server"` attribute. Try changing the main form to have the correct encoding type.

Comment: @Individual101 Like I said, try adding the correct encoding type to your form.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean.  Do I need to remove the runat="server" line and put in the enctype="multipart/form-data instead?

Comment: @Individual101 No, I didn't say anything about removing `runat="server"`. I said you can only have one form with the `runat="server"` attribute. So on that one form, add the correct encoding type attribute.

Comment: So I would then only have the 1 form liine that would read <form id="form1" class="forms" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" runat="server">?

Comment: @Individual101 Try it and see. You're the one with the code, I'm not sitting at your computer so I can't try it.

Comment: Well I dont know what I did wrong but now my page isnt going to the message received message when I click submit anymore.  With or without the enctype....

Comment: @Individual101 I don't know what you did either. Like I said, I'm not at your computer. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for source code control or basic debugging skills.

Comment: Ok I think I have this pretty well down pat.  I changed the string a little bit and now I come to the smtpClient.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, message.Subject, message.Body).  What do I add at the end in order to shoot out the attachment

Comment: @Individual101 You can't send an attachment with that overload of the `Send()` method. Go back to how you were doing it in your question, augmented with the code in my answer.

Comment: Ok it looks exactly like I have it in the question post.  I am able to complete the form and submit an email but everything but the attachment comes through.  On the HTML I have browsed to my file and found it.  Do I need to apply an upload button on that page or can it grab the file I browsed to and attach it.

Comment: @Individual101 I feel like you're going in circles. I've already explained how to verify if the file is being sent to the server, I've shown you how to grab the file on the server, and I've shown you how to attach the file to the email. You need to review what has been said here and play with your code.